# Flutter PDF Viewer with Form Fill Support

Tags: flutter, pdf

I'm looking for a PDF Viewer for Flutter with Form Fill Support.

Is there an alternative to this? https://pspdfkit.com/guides/flutter/forms/fill-form-fields/using-the-ui/

Comment: are you able to find free package for pdf edit or alternative of pspdf ?/